# Firebase CREDENTIAL for rest API

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Rest API mentions that we can pass CREDENTIAL to provide access to authenticated nodes. However I was not able to find documentation on where I can find these credential or generate these credential. Custom tokens generated using NodeJS firebase-admin client also don't work.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data

```
https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/saving-data/auth-example.json?auth=CREDENTIAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scrolled down [a little](http://If%20you%20scroll%20down%20a%20little,%20you'll%20find%20the%20answer:%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#auth) on the same page, you would find the answer:

> In the following example we send a POST request with an auth parameter, where CREDENTIAL is either our Firebase app secret or an authentication token...

- Firebase secrets are legacy credentials you can find/create under Project settings - Service Accounts in the Console. Using one as the `auth` parameter gives the caller administrative access.
- Or you can use a service account to generate admin level access tokens instead of relying on the legacy secrets. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth) for the Java implementation.
- Or if you have an authenticated user – for example you're implementing an API a client apps call via HTTP, passing along their current access token –, you can use that token directly to impersonate the user.

---

The custom authentication tokens serve a completely different purpose and are part of a different sign in flow. Therefore they do nothing via the REST API.

Comment: I used the code: firebase.database.enableLogging(true); and got the credentials in the console. Thanks a lot for timely help.